# Spring unknown property 'spring.cloud.config.server'

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I am attempting to connect to a git config server in my spring project following the example below in an eclipse IDE

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR5/

However I am running into issues being able to resolve the properties needed as eclipse is not able to recognize the server property in my bootstrap.yml (unknown property 'spring.cloud.config.server')

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      *server*:
        git:
          uri: .....config_server.git
```

I have included all the dependencies listed in the example above (spring-cloud-dependencies, spring-cloud-starter-config, spring-boot-starter-test) however I still receive the error.

Is there limitations as to when this property can be used? Or is there an additional dependency that is needed?

Comment: Where do you see the error from the title? Are you able to run the project from command line?

Answer (score 0):

> *This was added to the question by the OP and has been moved here.*

Turns I just needed to add a spring-cloud-starter-config-server dependency. Not sure why it did not get pulled in by by the others but that did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

here is a small example of how we use it using the spring cloud config:

***bootstrap.yml***

```
spring:
  profiles:
    # this will tell spring to pick the correct profile file
    active: sheba

  # u must specify your application name for it to be found in the git repository!    
  application:
    name: OpscI2aClient

  # now we telling our git client where to locate our config files
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        bootstrap: true

        git:
          # this the full uri to our repository where the config file
          # wich its name is ApplicationName-profileName.yml
          # are found
          uri: https://some.company.git.com/config/config-repo.git
          username: someGitUserName
          password: thePasswordOfTheGitUser
          # clone the whole config repository on startup
          the whole files in the repository are cloned!
          clone-on-start: true
          # this tell spring the name of the local repository directory
          # which in this case it shall create a directory called git_local
          relatively to where the application started
          basedir:
            git_local
```

so, assuming you have a git repo, it must contain a file OpscI2aClient-sheba.yml

this file is just a simple spring boot configuration file, however, should not contain active profile entry.
that is it.

Just to clarify:
Assuming the application named OpscI2aClient have two profiles, dev and prod,
your git configuration repositoty should actually contain, two files:
1. OpscI2aClient-dev.yml
2. OpscI2aClient-prod.yml

Hope this helps.

I am just adding the POM in which you might find some hints as well

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <project.scm.id>opsc-scm-server</project.scm.id>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.2</slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
        <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Thanks Gal. So that is what I am attempting to do, however the uri is never picked up because eclipses considers 'spring.cloud.config.server' to be unknown. It does not recognize this as a valid property.

Comment: I use STS (spring tool suite) for development which got a little better behavior with spring boot attributes. Now, though eclipse doesn't pick up the property, do you have an exception when running the app? Does it load your config? If it does and all your issue sums to attribute is not picked up by Eclipse, you could add it yourself  to the project at resources/META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json

Answer (score -1):

First of all, is it just Eclipse doesn't see server and you can run it from command line with no errors?
In case if it's just Eclipse it could be just wrong indention or tabs. Eclipse is not so smart sometimes.

- Try to set it all to plain application.properties file.
- Try to run it from command line

Also, I think you have to add credentials section for git + encrypted or not.

Here is valid example of YML that works fine in STS Eclipse:
https://github.com/zobarov/spring-cloud/blob/master/edu-springcloud-configserver/src/main/resources/application.yml

Comment: No, it does not pick up the uri property even if I attempt to run it. It defaults back to localhost. The issue is eclipse/spring does not recognize the sever level of properties as being valid.

Comment: Again, is it the same if you compile and run your app from command prompt?